# How can i re-order column name in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am practicing python code and reach to manipluation part where i tend to change order of the columns :

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd 

data= {"calories":[420, 380, 390],
      "duration":[50, 40, 45]
     }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

if i run above code, gives me calories first then duration, what I need to see first duration, then calories. I know if I change the series, I can achieve that, however as I advised I need to do that by code.

any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the column names in order, pandas will realign:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['duration', 'calories'])
```

If `df` already exists you need to slice or [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df[['duration', 'calories']]]

# or
df = df.reindex(columns=['duration', 'calories'])
```

Output:

```
   duration  calories
0        50       420
1        40       380
2        45       390
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on [pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
df.set_index(['calories', 'duration']).swaplevel().reset_index()
```

---

Or simply:

```
df.iloc[:, ::-1]
```

as @mozway suggests below (thanks!).

---

Output:

```
   duration  calories
0        50       420
1        40       380
2        45       390
```

Comment: Seems not really generic ;) If you just want to reverse the order, why not `df.iloc[:, ::-1]`?

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for commenting my answer! You are right! :-)